# ruby on rails 4 command line localization issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm developing a rails 4.1.1 application that uses custom inflections:

inflections.rb:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:es) do |inflect|
  inflect.plural /([taeiou])([A-Z]|_|\$)/, '\1s\2'
  inflect.plural /([rlnd])([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1es\2'
  inflect.singular /([taeiou])s([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1\2'
  inflect.singular /([rlnd])es([A-Z]|_|$)/, '\1\2'
end
```

and in the application.rb:

```
...
config.i18n.default_locale = :es
config.i18n.locale = :es
...
```

but when I try to generate a model it doesn't use the inflectors, I tryed opening a rails console and test using this command:

```
"direccion".pluralize
```

The answer was "direcions" wich is incorrect, the right answer is is "direcciones". What should I change so it uses my custom inflector at command line or in rails console so it can generate correctly my models?